# Why does my ourput only show a single element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to take a list as a parameter and find if each name in the list ends with a vowel. However for i keep getting a single element instead of all of them

```
a_list = ["Renjie",  "Shannon",  "Benjamin",  "Peron",  "Abhay",  "Peron",  "Ryan",  "Jingyi",  "David",  "Shan",  "Atunaisa",  "James",  "Joshua",  "Rory",  "Wayne",  "Raymond",  "Amy",  "Franco",  "Siran",  "Siyan",  "Dokyung",  "Hansoo",  "Adefolakanmi",  "Belita",  "Da",  "Qihao",  "Campbell",  "Chester",  "Daniel",  "alex",  "Rachel",  "Mitchell",  "Angelo",  "Bishoy",  "Freshteh",  "Kunyu",  "Lefei",  "Michael",  "alex",  "Minsuck",  "Angel",  "Sayaka",  "Changhao",  "Pramith",  "Minsang",  "Shuliang",  "Jiaqi",  "Mathew",  "Prashant",  "Alex"]
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
new_list = []
for word in a_list:
    if word[-1] in vowels:
       new_list.append(word)
       return new_list
```

Comment: Dedent the `return` statement out of the `for` loop. `return`ing terminates the execution of the function, as a result the first element gets added and then the execution finishes.

Answer (score 1):

As Jim already [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829251/why-does-my-ourput-only-show-a-single-element#comment66948287_39829251), you need to dedend the `return`. Aside from that, you can use a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [word for word in a_list if word[-1] in vowels]
```